# View in-memory canvas data?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, memory, canvas

I have an array of canvas tags being dynamically filled with image data, and I need to analyze the image data of the canvases for debugging. How may I view these in memory?

I can obviously paint them to an on-screen canvas, however that would be very time consuming and I'm looking for a solution similar to viewing variables in Chrome's watch list.

EDIT: I need to view the canvas data visually, rather than textually. I was asking for a way to do this without manually drawing the data of the in-memory canvases onto an on-screen canvas to save time. For example, in Firefox's developer toold, if you hover the source of an image or the CSS for the URL of an image, it shows a small tooltip with the image
[image: Screenshot of firefox dev tools]

I wanted something similar for the in-memory canvases

Comment: More clarity please :-) What do you mean by "analyze" and "view"? You can get the pixel information with `context.getImageData`.

Comment: @markE sorry for the ambiguity, I need to view the canvas data visually as opposed to textually

Answer (score 0):

Create a large on-screen canvas and use the scaling version of `context.drawImage` to draw multiple down-sized in-memory canvases to the on-screen canvas. You can view 4,6,8 smaller canvases at once on the big canvas. Kind of like the quad-screen security camera displays.

**[ Addition based on comment (and request for clarification) ]**

I don't know a way to do what you ask.

A canvas is not a variable. It's basically a bitmap.

If you want to view the pixel data you can use `context.getImageData`. What you would see is thousands of array elements all with values between 0-255.

Here's an example of the pixel data of an image:

3,45,117,255,2,46,119,255,4,48,123,255,2,49,127,255,3,51,133,255,2,52,137,255,2,54,140,255,1,55,143,255,7,74,152,255,8,71,148,255,7,69,146,255,5,69,141,255,5,74,143,255,2,82,145,255,1,92,149,255,0,97,152,255,31,92,175,255,15,86,174,255,0,79,99,255,0,48,121,255,10,30,177,255,21,35,144,255,1,33,134,255,0,46,155,255,0,44,174,255,0,57,120,255,0,51,121,255,0,37,167,255,9,50,156,255,2,52,125,255,15,67,168,255,0,53,162,255,15,71,168,255,4,63,153,255,1,62,145,255,14,69,152,255,9,64,155,255,9,83,182,255,14,121,225,255,0,124,232,255,11,120,223,255,11,124,228,255,7,124,229,255,2,123,228,255,8,131,235,255,16,138,239,255,10,130,227,255,0,115,209,255,2,123,238,255,0,123,233,255, ... and on for thousands of elements more.

If this is what you need, here's how to get it:

```
var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="yourImageSource";
function start(){

    canvas.width=img.width;
    canvas.height=img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

    var a=ctx.getImageData(0,0,cw,ch).data;

    var t="";
    var comma="";
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        t+=comma+a[i];
        comma=",";
    }
    console.log(t);
}
```

If that's not what you want, perhaps you could edit your question and better explain your need?

Comment: Thanks but I specifically said I didn't want to draw them on the screen to view them :-) I need to view them in the debugger similar to viewing any other variable

Comment: Ok, I added to my answer to show you how to get the red, green, blue & alpha data for every pixel on a canvas. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the further clarification, but no, there is no way to do this...sorry :-(